# Why my update query in my php fails?

Tags: php

I'm new in php.
Usually my update query is working, only in this block resulting a query fail, I get the officer value from `$_SESSION[id]` that determined before, and `contact_id` from a form before.
Please help...

```
<?php
$server="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$pass="h6194v";
$db="my_db";
$koneksi=mysql_connect($server,$db_user,$pass)
     or die ("Connection Error!!");
$dateline=date("Ymd");
$query="UPDATE `contact` SET `date`=\'$dateline\', `officer`=\'$_SESSION[id]\' WHERE `contact_id`=\'$_POST[no]\'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Query fail");
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting `Query fail` error ?

Comment: No need to escape single quotes.

Comment: Also, stop using mysql_* and don't pass session variables to an sql statement. YIKES!

Comment: yes i get a query fail messages

Comment: Change the `update` query like below

Comment: echo `$query` and paste here

Answer (score 2):

First of all

> Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, here is [good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Other than that and if you use mysql:

1. select a database after you made a connection with `mysql_select_db($db,$koneksi)` or use database name in front of the table name in UPDATE statement like `UPDATE my_db.contact ...`
2. fix your UPDATE statement as suggested by others
3. use correct format for date `date('Y-m-d')` or better yet ditch it altogether and use `NOW()` in your UPDATE statement

Answer (score 0):

I formatted your query and try this.

```
$query="UPDATE `contact` SET `date`='{$dateline}', `officer`='{$_SESSION['id']}' WHERE `contact_id`='{$_POST['no']}'";
```

Note: Dont use MySQL functions and they are deprecated instead use PDO or MySQLi functions. You code is open to SQL injection try to add validation or use prepared statement to protect.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
$query="UPDATE `contact` SET `date`='".$dateline."', `officer`='".$_SESSION['id']."' WHERE `contact_id`='".$_POST['no']."'";
```

But validate `$_POST` or `$_GET` before using in query or anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what kind of error you're getting.

1. Don't put user input or session variables straight into a query, you should sanitize them first, perhaps with prepared statements.
2. When you get an error like this, try using var_dump and die to see what's going on. I.e. before your query var_dump($_SESSION['id']). (And now that I write that, I see you don't have quotes on your array index, which will cause problems.

You need to access your array with quotes: $_SESSION['id'], $_POST['no']

Answer (score -1):

Change your `update` query like this

```
    $query="UPDATE `contact` SET `date`='".$dateline."', `officer`='".$_SESSION[id]."' 
WHERE `contact_id`=".$_POST[no];
```

If `contact_id` is string, do like this

```
$query="UPDATE `contact` SET `date`='".$dateline."', `officer`='".$_SESSION[id]."' 
WHERE `contact_id`='".$_POST[no]."'";
```

Comment: Just need to know why put minus mark for this ?

Comment: i have tried the cod but still return a Query fail message

Comment: This is not fair, you have to change accordingly. Can `echo` query and paste  here ?